# using silverstripe data object concept in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, silverstripe

I am new to wordpress, I come from Silvestripe development.

I have developed a FAQ accordion that has a tittle and description.

In silverstripe I would create a dataobject, relate it to the desired page and then output it by looping through the records in the template.

```
<div class="accordionContainer">
<ul>
    <% loop accordion %>    //loop data object          
              <li>
                  <h2 class="accordionHeader"><a href="#">$Title</a></h2>
                  <div class='accordionContent'>
                     <div class ="accordionBlock">
                         $Description
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </li>                          
    <% end_control %>
    </ul>  
    </div>
```

How can this be achieved in wordpress??

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The same way but different. Sorry, this is not enough information. Do you get your data from database? Through wordpress or via custom database access?

Comment: Currently not from the database. At the moment there are no FAQs created. That's what i need to create, some kind of data object with "title" and "description" fields, that I could connect in a relationship to the desired page and then use a loop in the template to get the results.

Comment: It would be a custom database in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Although WP now allows custom post types (like page types in Silverstripe), it looks like relationships may need to be handled by a plugin.

There are some details of a plugin here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/relation-post-types/ which suggests that one to many relationships can be achieved using it ("rented houses connected to an agency")